# Dropdown menu (SELECT element) not losing focus correctly in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-6

Example (load in IE6): http://jsbin.com/uheco/14

In IE6, if the user clicks on a `SELECT` and does not click any `OPTION` but instead clicks somewhere else on the page outside the `SELECT`, the `SELECT` still has focus.

I expected the `SELECT` to lose focus when I clicked once outside of it (such as in IEs 7 & 8).

Functions bound to the `blur` event are not called on the first click outside of the `SELECT`, but on the second: http://jsbin.com/uheco/11

Comment: Does this remain even if you focus another element explicitly?

Comment: No, but no other element will gain focus on the first click.

For example, (in IE6) if a user clicks the SELECT, and next clicks another form element, such as a TEXTAREA, the TEXTAREA will not gain focus (and the SELECT will not lose it). If clicked a second time, another element can gain focus.

Comment: @Jason I'd love to, please tell my users to stop using it until it falls below our drop rate

Comment: @devils - what % of your users use IE6? do you know for a fact how many?

Comment: @Jason 6.4%, 1.4% over the 5% min

Answer (score 0):

Use the `tabindex` attribute or the `focusout` event to fix blur in IE6:

- [blur and focus](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html)